# Which is the correct one "the next day" / "on the next day"

Tags: prepositions

He came the next day/
He came on the next day

Please tell which sentence is correct. Please explain why.

Comment: Including the word _on_ here is not wrong, but it's unnecessary. However, we _would_ say "He came on the day that X happened" or "on the last Friday in March".

Answer (score 0):

You could consider "the next day" as a **adverbial phrase**, so the sentence

> He came the next day

is grammatical and idiomatic.

Another example from Collins dictionary could verify this kind of use.

> But **the next day** my solicitor contacted me to say the money had not arrived.